In magento how to add paypal pay button in every product page
"I've enabled the 'Display on Product Details Page' option for PayPal in the admin portal (Store -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods -> PayPal), but the PayPal Pay button is not appearing on the product detail pages. How can I troubleshoot or ensure that the PayPal button is displayed on every product page?"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks for your attention. I’ve revised the question.

I discovered a solution for this issue in my scenario. The problem occurred because my Magento theme was outdated, which prevented buttons from displaying on the product details page. After updating the theme using the "composer update swissup/*" command, the PayPal and Stripe buttons were successfully enabled on the product details page.
